# Is there a way to have a docker container wait for an external call?

Tags: docker

I have looked for a bit on Stack Overflow for a way to have a container start up and wait for an external connection but have not seen anything.

Here is what my process looks like currently:

1. Non-Docker external process reaches out at X interval and tells system to run a command.
2. Command runs.
3. System should remain idle until the next interval.

Now I have seen a few options with `--wait` or `sleep` but I would think that would not allow the container to receive the connection.

I also looked at the wait for container script that is often recommended but in this case I need the container to wait for a script to call it on non defined intervals.

I have tried having this just run the help command for my process but it then fails the container after a bit of time and makes it a mess for finding anything.
Additionally I have tried to have the container start with no command just to run the base OS and wait for the call but that did not work either.

Comment: How would this be different from a server that listens on a port and responds to requests?

Comment: It isn't. I am working on this in my free time to convert a app that sits on a VM to a docker process to validate if it is possible.

Comment: I second @BMitch that you should run a server and have it execute requests for you. When you say "just to run the base OS and wait for the call", what is "wait for the call", what is waiting? How are commands sent a received?

Comment: If it's no different, then run a server. There are lots of examples out there, including webservers like nginx and database servers like postgresql.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of info here.
The external call is a job scheduler that runs at set times much like a cron job but with alerting to our teams.
The container I am attempting to just have sit there waiting is running a java based application that only kicks off from the external call. 
The flow is :
1. Scheduler/Cron system hits interval, then sends command of `<path to app> invoke.sh`
 2. Container should run the invoke script that is locally hosted. 

I get what you are saying about running a webserver and DB in a container, just not seeing how to kick that off for java.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this wrong.
Ended up just running like any other webserver and database server.